# Using CharFilter with Lucene 4.3.0's StandardAnalyzer

Tags: java, lucene

I am trying to add a `CharFilter` to my `StandardAnalyzer`.  My intention is to strip out punctuation from all the text I index; for example I want a PrefixQuery "pf" to match "P.F. Chang's" or "zaras" to match "Zara's".

It seems that the easiest plan of attack here is to filter out all punctuation before analysis.  Per the [Analyzer package documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/package-summary.html), that means I should use a `CharFilter`.

However, it seems next to impossible to actually insert a `CharFilter` into the analyzer!

The JavaDoc for [Analyzer.initReader](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer.html#initReader%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.Reader%29) says "Override this if you want to insert a CharFilter".

If my code extends Analyzer, I can extend initReader but I cannot delegate the abstract [createComponents](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer.html#createComponents%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.Reader%29) to my base StandardAnalyzer, as it is protected.  I cannot delegate [tokenStream](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer.html?is-external=true#tokenStream%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.Reader%29) to my base analyzer, because it is final.  So a subclass of Analyzer seemingly cannot use another Analyzer to do its dirty work.

There is an `AnalyzerWrapper` class that seems perfect for what I want!  I can provide a base analyzer and only override the pieces that I want.  Except … [initReader](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/AnalyzerWrapper.html#initReader%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.Reader%29) is overridden already to delegate to the base analyzer, and this override is "final"!  Bummer!

I guess I could have my `Analyzer` be in the `org.apache.lucene.analyzers` package and then I can access the protected `createComponents` method, but this seems like a disgustingly hacky way to bypass the public API that I really should use.

Am I missing something glaring here?  How can I amend a `StandardAnalyzer` to use a custom `CharFilter`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The intent is for you to override `Analyzer`, rather than `StandardAnalyzer`.  The thinking is that you should never subclass an Analyzer implementation (some discussion of there [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-3055)).  Analyzer implementations are pretty straightforward though, and adding a CharFilter to an Analyzer implementing the same tokenizer/filter chain as StandardAnalyzer would look something like:

```
public final class MyAnalyzer {
    @Override
    protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
        final StandardTokenizer src = new StandardTokenizer(matchVersion, reader);
        TokenStream tok = new StandardFilter(matchVersion, src);
        tok = new LowerCaseFilter(matchVersion, tok);
        tok = new StopFilter(matchVersion, tok, StopAnalyzer.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS_SET);
        return new TokenStreamComponents(src, tok);
    }

    @Override
    protected Reader initReader(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
        //return your CharFilter-wrapped reader here
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm, given that what I really want is "StandardAnalyzer with a CharFilter" this seems like a really heavy-handed way of doing it.  But it does look like this is going to be my only option.